# How to add JS validation on SharePoint new item form to check date field populated or not

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, task-list

I am working with a Task list in SharePoint online. On the new item form, I have a field called 'Due Date' (Internal name: DueDate) which is set to optional and for one of the Flow requirements, I have to keep it optional as upon making it required my existing flow logic will break.

So i am looking to see if validation can be added using JS. Basically when a user clicks on Save button on the new item form, the code should check if Due date field is populated or not, if not then it should show a message in red that you cannot leave due date empty. Once they populate, it should let them save.

Can anyone help me with the JS code.
P.S: Again I do not want to leverage OOTB required approach here, need a JS solution please.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction(){
    var dueDate=$("input[title='Due Date']").val();
    var entity = $("select[title='Entity ID Name']").val();


    if(dueDate.trim()==""){
        alert("Please select a Due Date.");
        return false;
    }
    if(entity.trim()==""){
    alert("Please populate Entity ID Name.");
    return false;
    }


    var getIDPeoplePicker=$("div[title='Assigned To']").attr("id");
    var ppobject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[getIDPeoplePicker];
    var usersobject = ppobject.GetAllUserInfo();
    if(usersobject.length==0){
        alert("Please select a user in Assigned To field.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

We can add the code below into a script editor web part in task list form page to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction(){
    var dueDate=$("input[title='Due Date']").val();
    if(dueDate.trim()==""){
        alert("Please select a Due Date.");
        return false;
    }
    if(!$("div[title='Assigned To']").find(".sp-peoplepicker-initialHelpText").is(":hidden")){
        alert("Please select a user in Assigned To field.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot LZ_MSFT. I also have a choice column called Entity and a people picker 'Assigned To, will the same logic work for these fields as well? PLease advise.

Comment: P.S: Works great for a choice column as well, I just select instead of Input. Can you please assist what needs to be used for AssignedTo people picker field?

Comment: I have modified the code in the reply to make it works for the Assigned To field.

Comment: I tested the code for assigned to field but its not working. Can you please assist. Thanks.

Comment: Using F12 to check if some errors messages occurs, in my test environment, it working fine.

Comment: I have added the console log and the code I am using in the question description, can you please review, thanks

Comment: Check my new update reply.

Comment: it does not work, it prompts when a user is not populated. Once I populate, it still shows me  message to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the validation for People Picker field through the following code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function PreSaveAction()
   {
     //assign value of people picker field to variable
     var AssignedTo = "Assigned To";
      Assigned = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[$('[title="' + AssignedTo + '"]')[0].id];

  //check if the variable contains values
   if (Assigned.TotalUserCount == 0) {
    alert("Please, Enter at least one User in Assigned To.");
    return false;
      }
        return true;
      }
   </script>
```

Comment: It does not work

Comment: i have updated my answer.